# How to dismiss a UIAlertView when touching anywhere outside of it?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

I need to dismiss an AlertView when the user touches anywhere outside of its bounds.

I know that you have to call

```
alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

to dismiss the AlertView, but how do I do it only when the user touches anywhere else besides one of the two buttons that are a part of the view?

This is the code I have after the suggestion from Steve:

```
presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    //Add gesture recognizer for alert ViewController when adding an event
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "alertClose:")
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    //dismiss the alert if the user click anywhere except the buttons
    func alertClose(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: could you add a UITapGestureRecognizer to view and then have that action call the alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated?

Comment: Maybe you can show a custom alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you present your alert call it with a completion handler like this:

```
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion:{
        alert.view.superview?.userInteractionEnabled = true
        alert.view.superview?.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.alertClose(_:))))
})
```

**Note:** Pre Swift 2.2 replace

```
#selector(self.alertClose(_:))
```

with

```
Selector("alertClose")
```

then create your alert close function:

```
func alertClose(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

I tested this with swift 2.2 on an iPhone 6

Comment: this should work, just make a reference to your alert

Comment: I tried this code but it doesn't seem to work. Do I call presentViewController before or after the above code?

Comment: I get a caution: No method declared with Objective-C selector 'alertClose:'

Comment: @ZDaws  it appears that syntax is deprecated in swift 2.  It wants "alertClose:" replaced with #selector(ViewController.alertClose(_:))  however it doesn't seem to work because taps on viewController are ignored while the alert is up

Comment: @ZDaws - check my update.  Had a chance to test it on a device and it works

Comment: @Steve I get an error when using #selector. It says that it refers to a method not exposed to Objective-C.

Comment: @ZDaws, it worked for me with no error do you have a typo in the name of the function? where are you defining the function?  also what version of xCode are you using this was with 7.3.

Comment: @Steve I fixed the error. If you use Selector("alertClose") it works just fine.

Comment: @ZDaws, cool just a heads up when you transition to swift 2.2 it will want you to use the #selector call.  The #selector checks your code at compile time to make sure the function exists.  String literals are not therefore a bad function reference will be caught at runtime instead.  See more info here https://swift.org/blog/swift-2-2-new-features/

Comment: ok I updated the answer to reflect Swift 2.2 and pre 2.2 differences